# Move a dataframe (including it's column names) down a row, then insert a row above with another header

Tags: r, rstudio

I have a dataframe and trying to insert a second header row.
Is it possible to move the dataframe down a row and then insert a row above with another header.
Here is an example of the data I have.

```
Variable <- c("Age 0-15", "Age 16-29", "Age 30-44", "Age 45-54", "Age 55-64", "Age 65+")
Percentage <- c(.1,.2,.3,.25,.15,.05 )
N <- c(50,100,150,125,75,25)
df <- data.frame(Variable,Percentage,N)
df
> df
   Variable Percentage   N
1  Age 0-15       0.10  50
2 Age 16-29       0.20 100
3 Age 30-44       0.30 150
4 Age 45-54       0.25 125
5 Age 55-64       0.15  75
6   Age 65+       0.05  25
```

I'd like to move the df down, and then insert a row above with the name (for example "Segment A") in each cell above the dataframe. This how I'd like the data to look

```
V1 <- c("Segment A", "Variable","Age 0-15", "Age 16-29", "Age 30-44", "Age 45-54", "Age 55-64", "Age 65+")
V2 <- c("Segment A", "Percentage",.1,.2,.3,.25,.15,.05 )
V3 <- c("Segment A", "N",50,100,150,125,75,25)
df_result <- data.frame(V1,V2,V3)
df_result

> df_result
         V1         V2        V3
1 Segment A  Segment A Segment A
2  Variable Percentage         N
3  Age 0-15        0.1        50
4 Age 16-29        0.2       100
5 Age 30-44        0.3       150
6 Age 45-54       0.25       125
7 Age 55-64       0.15        75
8   Age 65+       0.05        25
```

I understand the variables will no longer be numeric, but I just need it to be able to export the table for reporting purposes. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Although you _can_ do something like `setNames(rbind(list("a", "a", "a"), as.list(names(df)), df), NULL)`, I think it's better to use a dedicated tool for printing / formatting (there are many nice packages; just google "format tables R").

Answer (score 1):

If you need the table for reporting purposes, you could try something like this:

```
library(kableExtra)
library(magrittr)
df %>%
  kable() %>%
  add_header_above( rep( "Segment A", 3) )
```

[image]